# How can I make alertDialog disappear automatically after few seconds in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

An alertDialog is to be shown when a button is tapped and disappear automatically after few seconds. How can I do that in Flutter?

Comment: see `Future<T>.delayed` constructor

Answer (score 60):

A Minimal E.g:

It Closes the `alertDialog` after 5 seconds.

```
           showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                        });
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Title'),
                        );
                      });
```

Comment: and if the dialog barrierDismissible is true, will it be a problem for the delayed on pop it?

Comment: it is not good solution
because after close dialog with user request 
 Future.delayed start working and it closes another page

Comment: Downvoted, this will cause users dimiss unexpected page.

Comment: As pointed out by the multiple people above, if you want to use this snippt, remmber to set barrierDismissible to false, otherwise there will be problem when you cancel the window before the time elapses.

Answer (score 21):

`Future.delayed` can cause some problems if you dismiss the dialog before the Future is triggered.
So, if you use it be careful that the showDialog is not dismissable `barrierDismissible: false` and that the AlertDialog hasn't buttons that dismiss it.

Otherwise, you can use a Timer:

```
Timer timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 3000), (){
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
});
showDialog(
  ... Dialog Code ...
).then((value){
  // dispose the timer in case something else has triggered the dismiss.
  timer?.cancel();
  timer = null;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a 'SnackBar' to show notice that disappears automatically.

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('This is where you put the notice.'),
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
);
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: hi, I try this in channel master, and showSnackBar was deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use FutureBuilder so this would be dismissed automatically when the user close the dialog before the timeout passed.

```dart
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.delayed(dismissDuration).then((value) => true),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }

            return AlertDialog(
              content: Text(text),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```